# Why is some of my code being skipped?

Tags: c

My program is exhibiting some odd behavior when I step through it in the debugger. In the following excerpt, it checks `pktNum != ~invPktNum` and then proceeds directly the the second `return 1;` statement.

The debugger shows that `pktNum` is an unsigned char that is 0x01 and `invPktNum` is an unsigned char that is 0xFE.

```
/* Verify message integrity. */
if (pktNum != ~invPktNum) {
    return 1;
}
ccrc = crc16_ccitt(msg, XModem_Block_Size);
if ( (((ccrc>>8) & 0xFF) != crcBuf[0]) 
    || ((ccrc & 0xFF) != crcBuf[1]) ) {
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: OH MY GOD! It did exactly what you told it to - it tested that 0x1 != 0, and returned 1.  Stop the presses!

Comment: Sorry, I meant '~'. I changed it to '!' because i thought 0x01 and ~0xFE would be equal, but my code still doesn't seem to think so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler has folded the two `return 1` cases into the exact same code.  Both `if` tests branch to the same assembly instruction.  Each instruction can only be tagged with a single line number for the debugger, so you see that strange behavior.  If you compile with `-g` and *without* `-O` (or even more explicitly use `-O0`) it will make distinct cases and things will be more clear.

Comment: But there are no line numbers at all without -g, right? I'd say that it's more of a matter of disabling any -O in the compiler flags. Still a good point, though. +

Answer (score 3):

Unary `!` is logical-NOT.  If the operand is `0` the result is `1`, otherwise the result is `0`.  This means that `!invPktNum` is `0`, so the `if` expression is true.

You are probably looking for unary `~`, which is bitwise-NOT.

---

By the way, it may appear in a debugger as if the second `return 1;` is being executed rather than the first, because the compiler may have reordered the code and combined those two `return 1;` statements together (particularly if optimisation is enabled).

Answer (score 2):

`!(0xFE)` is `0`. Maybe what you wanted was `~(0xFE)`?

Answer (score 0):

Check compiler optimizations are definitely disabled for debug mode. (Just to be different to everybody else)

Answer (score -1):

You're comparing an int to a bool. That's bad style to begin with, and some compilers will complain.

Maybe you mixed up `!` and `~`? `!invPktNum` will return false if invPktNum is non-false, and true if it's false. I'm pretty sure you meant `~invPktNum`.

Comment: The result of `!` is an `int`.